# Projection issue between WGS84 and EPSG:2100

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, wgs84

I got a new GNSS receiver (Sparkfun RTK Faucet) and I also setup my base station. Now I am collection GPS date points down to an accuracy of about 14mm.

My goal is to convert the data points to the Greek land referencing system. So I got a land survey (done by a professional) that uses the [EPSG:2100 (egsa 87)](https://epsg.org/crs_2100/GGRS87-Greek-Grid.html) coordinate system and tried to recreate it.

My issue is when I put my WGS84 GPS points into Google Earth/Maps the points are spot on (Great). When I put the coordinates done by the professional into the Greek land referencing system, they are spot on (almost). But whatever conversion I try, the best I can do is about 2m away.

I loaded into QGIS as a background Google Maps and imported my points (pink) with a CRS EPSG:4326, However when I load in the professional coordinates with a CRS of EPSG:2100 (blue) they are out. Following this  I took a distance between 2 points, my points give a correct distance using ellipsoidal and the professional using coordinates.

My projection in QGIS (bottom right) is set to EPSG:2100

Am I missing something? Both sets of points should be in the same spot, and the distances the same. This is why I think it must be a projection issue.

Sample data points CSV:
GGRS87:
Label,  X,  Y,
K1, 126606.67,  4408960.77,
K2, 126618.28,  4408965.26,
K3, 126620.93,  4408958.40,
K4, 126609.32,  4408953.91

My GNSS GPS:
Label,  Lat,    Long,
K1, 39.751416005,   19.643969517,
K2, 39.75145978,    19.644103566,
K3, 39.751399245,   19.644136568,
K4, 39.751354588,   19.644001655

I am using QGIS 3.32.3

[image: Land survey, pink WGS84, blue egsa 87]

Comment: The image is not visible. Please upload correctly.